# How can I use the return value of a C# switch statement to exit a Task with a true or false?

Tags: c#, task

I have this code:

```
public async Task PickCard()
{
    switch (Settings.Co)
    {
        case CO.Random: Random(); break;
        case CO.FirstToLast: ArrangeCardOrder(true); break;
        case CO.LastToFirst: ArrangeCardOrder(false); break;
    }
    await ShowCard();
}
```

I am going to be modifying `Random()`, `ArrangeCardOrder(true)` and `ArrangeCardOrder(false)` to return a `true` or `false`.

Is there a way that I can get that information from the switch and if they methods return `true` then call `await ShowCard` and then exit PickCard with a true and if the methods return `false`, simply exit PickCard with a `false`?

Comment: surely you set  bool to the return of the method called and use that

Comment: just use a variable to store the return value and a conditional statement testing this variable before calling ShowCard...

Comment: and use `Task<bool>` as the return type if you want your async method to return a result. You can then use it like `if(await PickCard())` to use the result  elsewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently that's just a switch *statement*. To use a switch *expression* you need to change the syntax a bit - as well as using C# 8. You'll also want to change the return type so that `PickCard` can indicate the result.

```cs
public async Task<bool> PickCard()
{
    // This is a switch *expression* instead of a switch *statement*.
    // Switch expressions were introduced in C# 8.
    bool result = Settings.Co switch
    {
        CO.Random => Random(),
        CO.FirstToLast => ArrangeCardOrder(true),
        CO.LastToFirst => ArrangeCardOrder(false),
        // Adjust for whatever you want to do
        _ => throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid setting")
    }

    if (result)
    {
        await ShowCard();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Can obviously be adjusted to fit your exact needs better...

```
var succeeded = false;

switch (Settings.Co)
{
    case CO.Random: 
        succeeded = Random(); 
        break;
    (...)    
}

var result = false;
if(succeeded){
    result = await ShowCard();

    // or alternatively:
    // await ShowCard();
    // return true;
}

return result;
```